# Deploy private repository as dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

We have constructed our app to consist of three repositories:

1. Frontend (this one is deployed)
2. Shared
3. Core

These are all private Git repositories on GitHub.

The relevant part of my package.json file looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.x",
    "coffeecup": "0.3.x",
    "socket.io": "0.8.x",
    "connect-mongodb": "1.x",
    "app-core": "git+ssh://git@github.com:...git",
    "app-shared": "git+ssh://git@github.com:...git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mongoskin": "*",
    "bcrypt": "*",
    "libxml-to-js": "0.3.x"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "app-core",
    "app-shared"
  ],
  "analyze": true
```

When I deploy to Nodejitsu the only way to make it work is to have Shared and Core's dependencies in devDependencies of the repository I deploy, but that seems to be the wrong solution as devDependencies is meant for development and not production.

I have also tried [Shrinkwrapping](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/) but with no avail.

Does anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

`"bundleDependencies"` should work. When you `jitsu deploy`, it will analyze dependencies and try to add them, but you can disable this with `--noanalyze`. If you have your dependencies in `node_modules/app-core` and `node_modules/app-shared`, then I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you show me more information, like the output of `jitsu deploy`?

EDIT: Oh, I see, you have them in `devDependencies` so that they don't install on Nodejitsu. Yeah, I guess that's how it would you would do it, unless you just wanted to bundle the dependencies as submodules, and not even have them inside `dependencies` or `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only ssh to github from your own machine.

Change the repo url from `git+ssh://git@github.com...` to `https://github.com/...`

Comment: At Nodejitsu you can not have your private SSH key, so private reps can't be fetched, thus I need bundleDependencies.